# How to setup and use a UART serial interrupt on the RPI PIco?

Tags: pi-pico, interrupts, micropython

I have a data logging pico and want to add an interrupt on the serial port that can take in a string and report back the right amount of data stored on the SD card. I was looking at UART.irq but that doesn't work on the Pico. How should I go about setting up this interrupt and data output?

Answer (score 0):

Since SDK version 1.5.0 there is a function `stdio_set_chars_available_callback()` (pico/stdio.h)
Sorry, I just saw that your problem is related to MicroPython and not the C API

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the input anyway. It might lead me to a good answer.